# How does C++ store global variables?

Tags: c++, global-variables

I tested the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Test {
public:
    Test(const char *name) :name(name) { std::cout << name << ": constructing " << this << std::endl; }
    ~Test() { std::cout << name << ": destructing " << this << std::endl; }
private:
    const char *name;
};

Test global("global");
Test global2("global2");

int main() {}
```

To my surprise, the output turns out to be

```
global: constructing 0x104f84000
global2: constructing 0x104f84008
global2: destructing 0x104f84008
global: destructing 0x104f84000
```

But as far as I know, the address of heap variables goes down one by one. Why does it increase in the case of global variables?

Comment: The standard doesn't say anything about whether stack or heap variables grow up or down or anything like that. That's purely up to the implementation and not something you can rely on - different implementations can do different things.

Comment: Side note : In general just try to avoid globals (specially in big projects and/or when you want to be able to unit test).

Comment: To learn about the concrete implementation, you might want to start with the linker documentation, and read the relevant ABI standard.

Comment: String literals are not on the heap

Comment: Global variables are not stored on the stack or the heap.

Comment: Global variables are in **static** storage (commonly implemented by compilers in `.bss` or `.data`).  In contrast to **automatic** storage (commonly implemented by the compiler on the stack), or **dynamic** storage (commonly implemented by the compiler on the heap).  q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Answer (score -1):

If you see the memory layout of any process,the global variables are stored in data segment of processes memory. In any process the lowest address is of the code segment,which contains the instructions to be executed in the process. And then next is the data segment, it contains all the global variables.So, here as you can see the addresses of global variables are increasing.

Comment: The memory layout might be compiler and/or system specific (for dynamic loadable libraries even randomized). So generalizing like this might be confusing.

Comment: This is what we were taught in my university course
e.g here  https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs225/fa2022/resources/stack-heap/

Comment: There are always assumptions (in any teaching material) to keep things simple and teachable. And this material seems to have assumed a very simple hardware configuration. This is the way it might be on single core embedded processor with limited memory. Anyway C++ standard doesn't specify at all how memory must be used and/or managed.

Comment: @maximusPrime11 Just because you were taught something at university doesn't make it true.